# Get div attributes via Hpricot

Tags: html, ruby, parsing, hpricot

I've got a specific div id called progress_bar ()

And I'm trying to retrieve just the width of the div. I'm fairly new to Ruby and Hpricot so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,
Scott

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the `width` attribute is set in the HTML something like this should work according to the docs:

```
doc = Hpricot("my html")
(doc/"#progress_bar")['width']
```

Found here: https://github.com/hpricot/hpricot